# Bundle sha3/binary modules with Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, sha

Webpack warns when I bundle my source as it can't resolve the 'sha3' module.

```
$ npm run build
WARNING in ./~/keccakjs/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sha3' in '<PROJ>\node_modules\keccakjs'
 @ ./~/keccakjs/index.js 2:19-34
 @ ./~/<lib>/index.js
 @ ./lib/<file>.js
```

Reason being the [sha3 library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha3) has no ***js files***.

> Creating library **<proj>**\node_modules\sha3\build\Release\sha3.lib and object **<proj>**\node_modules\sha3\build\Release\sha3.exp

I am able to run `require('sha3')` in my project, however webpack cannot resolve it.

I looked at the [docs here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/), regarding how webpack resolves libs.

Could someone point me to how I can include sha3 in/with my bundle.

My Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: "./<lib>.js",
    devtool: "source-map",
    node: {
        __dirname: false,
        __filename: false,
    },
    output: {
        path: "./dist",
        filename: "<lib>.min.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What actually ended up working for me was:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        sha3: path.join(__dirname,'node_modules/sha3/build/Release/sha3.node')
    },
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {test: /\.node$/, use: 'node-loader'},
    ]
},
```

That way I told it which file to import, when it wasn't able to resolve `sha3`. And the [***`node-loader`***](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/node-loader/) packages in the `.node` file!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the binary loader from webpack from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-loader). Then you can:

1) Define loaders in your WebPack config:

```
module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: "./<lib>.js",
    devtool: "source-map",
    node: {
        __dirname: false,
        __filename: false,
    },
    output: {
        path: "./dist",
        filename: "<lib>.min.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /sha3$/, loader: 'binary' }
        ]
    }
}
```

2) Use the loader directly in your import:

```
require('binary!sha3');
```

Comment: Looks promising!

Comment: Getting `configuration has an unknown property 'loaders'`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, that's supposed to be inside a module object, I think I got a little confused when I saw module.exports. Edited!

Comment: It's still not working :/. Even when I add this: `externals: {
        "sha3": "keccak",
    },`